# Running Signalr in IIS on .Net Core - hub being hit but client sees 500 error

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, signalr

I have a .net core application deployed to IIS. There is a signalr hub in the application.

My problem is that when my client hits the hub it receives a 500 error back.

I have put logging in the hub and can see that it is being hit correctly and no exceptions are being thrown.

The setup works perfectly when run from Visual Studio.

I am thinking something might not be set up in IIS correctly.

Does anyone have any ideas that this might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I enabled the generic error page in the api and looking at the network tab in the browser I was able to see the call that signalr was making.

I looked at the content of this request and found that an error with the following message was being returned by the server...

**The data protection operation was unsuccessful**

After some searching I found that this was being caused due to a setting on the IIS application pool.

The steps to change the setting were...

1. Open **IIS Manager**
2. Select **Applications Pools**, and go ahead and select the App Pool used by your app
3. Right-click on it, and select **Advanced Settings**, Go to the **Process Model Section** and Find the **“Load User Profile”** Option and set it to **True**

These steps were taken from http://puresourcecode.com/dotnet/post/ASPNET-The-data-protection-operation-was-unsuccessful